# Can you turn on flyspell for comments but NOT strings?

Tags: flyspell, spell-checking

I currently use the following to enable `flyspell` in `prog-mode`:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'flyspell-prog-mode)
```

This checks spelling automatically in comments and strings. However, I would like to disable spell checking in strings.

**How can I enable `flyspell` for comments but not strings?**

Answer (score 10):

Here's a quick trip down the `flyspell` source code rabbit hole. (Try `C-h l flyspell` to get to it.)

`flyspell-prog-mode` uses `flyspell-generic-progmode-verify`.
That function uses text properities to decide whether or not to fire
based on whether or not the text property of the previous character
is a member of `flyspell-prog-text-faces`.

Now, the `flyspell-prog-text-faces` docstring tells me that, by
 default:

> `flyspell-prog-text-faces` is a variable defined in `flyspell.el`.
>   Its value is `(font-lock-string-face font-lock-comment-face font-lock-doc-face)`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Faces corresponding to text in programming-mode buffers.

So we can just remove `font-lock-string-face` from this list:

```el
(setq flyspell-prog-text-faces
      (delq 'font-lock-string-face
            flyspell-prog-text-faces))
```

Et voila.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify what flyspell-prog considers "text to be spelled" by customizing the `flyspell-prog-text-faces` variable:

```
;; original value: '(font-lock-string-face font-lock-comment-face font-lock-doc-face)
(setq flyspell-prog-text-faces '(font-lock-comment-face font-lock-doc-face)
```

Comment: Looks like we were typing at the same time!

Comment: I take my hat off (and upvote you) as you were more educational 